# pip install grpcio fails to build but worked 2 weeks before

Tags: python, docker, pip, grpc

I had to update a part of my code and started my CI/CD pipeline. It worked two weeks ago, but now it stops with the following error message.

```
Running setup.py install for grpcio: started
Running setup.py install for grpcio: still running...
Running setup.py install for grpcio: still running...
Running setup.py install for grpcio: still running...
Running setup.py install for grpcio: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-c8t74nfl/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-c8t74nfl/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-og68hhuf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.6m/grpcio
          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-c8t74nfl/grpcio/

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-c8t74nfl/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-c8t74nfl/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-og68hhuf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.6m/grpcio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here is the content of the docker file:

```
FROM harrisbaird/scrapyd:py3

# configure python app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
COPY user_agents.txt /usr/src/app/

RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
   lapack-dev \
   gcc \
   freetype-dev \
   bash \
   curl \
   openssl

RUN apk --update add python3  python3-dev

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
   gfortran \
   musl-dev \
   g++
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN pip install --upgrade six

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# removing dependencies
RUN apk del .build-deps

ADD app /usr/src/app

COPY ./scrapyd.conf /etc/scrapyd/

RUN scrapyd & PID=$! && \
  echo "Waiting for Scrapyd to start" && \
  sleep 2 && \
  [ ! -f /usr/src/app/scrapy.cfg ] || scrapyd-deploy && \
  kill $PID

RUN ln -s /usr/src/app/crawl /etc/periodic/daily/crawl

ENV WORKDIR=/usr/src/app

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

CMD ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Since all of my DevOps guy are on vacation drinking beer and having party, I really dont know how to get my application running again. Please support me with some hints. Thank you very much